# JavaScript // Accessing objects through functions

Tags: javascript, function, object

Have a simple function for init. lon and lat coordinates and this function returns the object with them.

```js
function initPosMethod() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    return navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(initKoord);
  }
}

function initKoord(position) {
    var koordObj = {
        lan:position.coords.latitude,
        lon:position.coords.longitude
    };
    
    return koordObj;
}

initPosMethod();
```

So my question is, how it is possible, to get access to the 'koordObj'?

This is not working:

```js
alert(initPosMethod.koordObj.lan);
```

Comment: Should call the function initPostMethod inside the alert, like :
alert( initPosMethod().lan );
i think the call does not return a "koordObj" just return the Object so dot lan or lon
but that's possible if change the return of navigator.geolocation coz is undefined..